# Azure data factory copy activity error records exception handling

Tags: exception, error-handling, record, azure-data-factory

In copy-activity, there is a feature in the settings where we can tell the system what to do on an error. There are 3 options available. Abort on first error-record, skip all error-rows, skip error-rows and log them.
Can we achieve the following functionality somehow?
- If there are more than 10% of records in the file throws error then skip that file, else load

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, please let me know if you have a better one
- Load the data to the target using fault-tolerance setting as "skip and log incompatible rows"
- We will get the total number of rows reached the copy-activity and number of rows that went into the target. From those 2 numbers we can calculate the %.
- if that % is more than 10 (or the threshold), remove data from the target and notify the relevant team or put that into the audit log

FYI - this feature is available in snowflake-DW, if we are directly using scripts to load data.